# Hibernate One to One, not generating Foreign key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 4 tables here: Register, User, User roles and User Profile Image

Register and User are mapped my a One to One relationship and a reference of Register is generated in Users table...... This is fine..

Now talking about One to Many Relation between User and the Roles table, it also works perfectly by generating a User table reference in the roles table..

But problem is when working with One to One between User and the Profile Image. **Profile Image is not generating reference of User**....Why the user reference is not generated in Profile Image table

**Register**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Register {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true,mappedBy = "register")
    private User user;

}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "User_Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserProfileImage userProfileImage;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<UserRoles> userRoles;

}
```

**User Profile Image**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserProfileImage {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "picByte", length = 100000)
    private byte[] picByte;

    public UserProfileImage() {
        super();
    }

    public UserProfileImage(String name, String type, byte[] picByte) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.picByte = picByte;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your annotations you told your Entities that the Foreign key that models the 1-to-1 relationshsip between `User` and `UserProfileImage` should be made in the Table for `User` with a column named `user_id` (Which is quite confusing, something like `user_profile_image_id` would make more sense logically).  So that is where you should look and expect your reference to be. If you want the FK to be generated in the table of UserProfileImage you need to change your annotations to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Profile mapping in User class is not correct and in your profile class there is no user field and hence it's not generating the user reference in the profile class.

Also, User to Roles mapping is also not correct, your user class will not populate roles with your mappings.

Try this:

```
public class User {

    ...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_IMAGE_ID")   // foreign key column in User table
    private UserProfileImage userProfileImage;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="user")
    private List<UserRoles> userRoles;

}


public class UserProfileImage {
    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="userProfileImage")
    private User user;

    ...
}

public class UserRole {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")  // foreign key column in User Role table
    private User user;

    ...
}
```